# React-router-dom V6 don't change route correctly (refresh - f5 page is required)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom, react-functional-component

I'm trying to apply basic route for my Reactjs app with functional component, and Material UI. I put <Link to .../> on navbar and expected when click Menu Item (Cart, Contact, Product) in navbar, content of page will change (just keep Header and Footer of page).

It is done with  is worked, when click each Menu Item, URL change. But the page will not change, i have to reload page for content change. I don't understand why get this issue.

Image and details step of this issue:
Step 1: When path is "/": [image: Home Page]
Step 2: Click Menu Item (Our Product), URL change "/product" but page does not change: [image: URL change]
Step 3: Have to reload page for see content of page change to  component: [image: Reload page]

Below is my code and file structure:

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Content from "./Content";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Product from "./Product/Product";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Content />} />

          <Route path="/product" element={<Product />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

export default App;

Header.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
const pages = ["Our Products", "Cart", "Contact"];
const settings = ["Profile", "Account", "Dashboard", "Logout"];
const links = ["/product", "/cart", "/contact"];

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app__header">
      . . .{/* render navbar */}
      <div className="header__nav">
        <Box
          sx={{
            gap: 20,
            flexGrow: 1,
            display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
          }}
        >
          {pages.map((page, index) => (
            <Link to={links[index]} textDecoration="none">
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: "white", display: "block" }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </Box>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Product.js: (sample text for test)

```
import React from 'react'

function Product() {
  return (
    <div>Product</div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

Config.json:

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce-web-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.7.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.11.0",
    "@splidejs/react-splide": "^0.7.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "swiper": "^8.1.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Header` component *into* the `Router` so the `Link` components it renders are working and updating the same routing context the routes are rendered in. There should have been an invariant warning/error regarding rendering the `Link` components outside a `Router`. If there is no such error/warning this is indicative of rendering the links into a separate router/routing context. You need only a single router for the entire app, so remove any other extraneous routers you might have in your app.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Header /> // <-- move into Router
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Content />} />
          <Route path="/product" element={<Product />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! And you have any more notice for me? I have already move Header into Router but it render a blank page with the following err in console: `Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.`

Comment: @GiangAn why you import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom" in Header.js? I think you had been use it in Header.js and this make that error

Comment: @GiangAn Ah, I had considered that might be the case. You only need 1 router for the entire app, so remove all but the one in `App` wrapping the header and routes. If there is one higher than `App` then remove the router that `App` is rendering.

Comment: @VMT thanks so much for your suggest, your idea combine with Drew Reese was solve my problem!